# python-hypothesis: Retrieving or reformatting a falsifying example

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

Is it possible to retrieve or reformat the falsifying example after a test failure? The point is to show the example data in a different format - data generated by the strategy is easy to work with in the code but not really user friendly, so I'm looking at how to display it in a different form. Even a post-mortem tool working with the example database would be enough, but there does not seem to be any API allowing that, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`note`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/details.html#hypothesis.note) to record additional information during a test, such as your own custom-formatted copy of the generated inputs.

When Hypothesis finds a falsifying example, it will also print out the notes that were recorded the execution of that particular example.

Comment: Well, it's not perfect, with `Verbosity.normal` tracebacks and other messages are still there (in my case they are pretty useless if not confusing for the user), with `Verbosity.quiet` even notes are gone. But I can work with that, I guess, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Even a post-mortem tool working with the example database would be enough, but there does not seem to be any API allowing that, or am I missing something?

The example database uses a private format and only records the choices a strategy made to generate the falsifying example, so there's no way to extract the data of the example short of re-running the test.

Stuart's recommendation of `hypothesis.note(...)` is a good one.